# Edit : if statement when checking for false (if(variable){} equivalent for false)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, expo

Context : I am trying to reduce my code for a reactjs project that I am working on using expo. In one of my if else statements, one boolean variable's value is changed based on whether any of multiple other boolean variables are false. I wanted to make this much more optimized and remove unnecessary code since its for a mobile app.

My question is : Is there a way to make an if statement shorter while checking whether a variable is false?

```
if(variable){}
```

is the same as

```
if(variable === true){}
```

Is there a way like this for false as well? Maybe something like

```
if(!variable){}
```

I'm not exactly sure and couldn't find any method similar to what I showed above anywhere online (yet).

Example of the code I have right now :

```
var example = false

if(var1 === false || var2 === false || var3 === false || var4 == false){
example = true
}
```

if **any** of the variables are false (hence the ||), it should switch over

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (!var)` is the equivalent of `var == false`

Comment: The first assumption is incorrect. The first condition checks for a truthy value which, as far as I know, is not the same as a strict comparison to true.

Comment: "I am trying to optimize" (in context of execution speed), "i am trying to make some `if` statement look nicer by being shorter" - premature optimization alarm goes wee-woo. Please decide, whether you want to make the code more readable (which is a good intention), or whether you want to make it run faster (where this issue is negligible).

Comment: Var example = (var1 === false || var2 === false .... )  ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be exactly the same as long as varN is already a boolean:

```
var example = false
if(var1 && var2 && var3 && var4){
    example = true
}
```

But it must by said that premature optimizations rarely lead to improvements. Most often the interpreter already takes care of any optimizations like that. And the speed-increas one can get by changing simple comparisons are close to none.

So I would rather keep it in the most readable state than the most optimized.

Comment: One thing that I didn't mention in the question was that my main pc broke. Im using another machine and since windows worked on my pc but I cant get node files in windows here, I have to use a virtual machine to run ubuntu and do it from there. It gets extremely laggy hence I'm trying to lighten the load wherever I can. I've created like 5 booleans just so I dont have to copy paste 10-15 if statements for all my parameters. I understand your point though and this helps a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
you can use some()

```
if([var1,var2,var3,var4].some((item)=> item === false) ){
   example = true
 }
```

Comment: But would this work if any of them are false? like not if all 4 variables, just any of the 4. My code requires the example variable here so that I don't need to use 'or'. It seems here that only if every one of them is false, example becomes true. Not sure if I understand the concept correctly but will read up on it. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it must be .some()

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version:

```js
var example = false

if (!(var1 && var2 && var3 && var4)) {
    example = true
}
```

I wouldn't call this "optimization" and I don't think there's anything wrong with your code to begin with.

Comment: I know that this part of my code isn't wrong, just that I have to repeat this process multiple times and since im using external files and a barcode scanner in my code, I will have to repeat this process multiple times in order to get a bug free result when I type in 2 parameters in my textInputs. Basically, in order for my concept to work, I have  to paste this multiple times in other places and it gets super laggy.